# Handling a click event of jsx element in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the following initial state in the reducer:

```js
const formatTypesDescriptions = [
    {
        title: 'Calendar',
        intro: <p>Calendar displays time <code>relative</code> to the <code>date picked</code>.
        <a onClick={() =>  console.log('Toggle Calendar') }>Click Here</a> to open the calendar</p>
    }
]


const initState = {
    formatTypesDescriptions,
    calendarIsVisible: false
}

const customVariables = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_CALENDAR_VISIBILITY:
            return {
                ...state,
                calendarIsVisible: !state.calendarIsVisible
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I know it's an anti-pattern in redux to call an action from the reducer. My problem is that the descriptions may be localized in multiple languages, so i should add multiple objects of that description in multiple languages including a link.

How can i handle the event from the jsx element in the app's state?

Comment: Why are you putting JSX in the state?

Comment: @AminPaks i've mentioned that  `the descriptions may be localized in multiple languages, so i should add multiple objects of that description in multiple languages including a link`, the link may exist in any place in the text when switching language

Comment: You may do all those things in the component conditionally. With the help of react-intl. the only thing you need is whats the current language

Comment: I actually need to add the language content without any translation/other plugin @AminPaks

Comment: The point is you should render everything inside your component that displays the text. Keep the language/flag in the state so you know what language should be displayed.

Comment: Always save only data in redux, and in component handle all html/jsx.

Comment: @AminPaks what if i wanted to add a span tag to color  a part of that text... (data)?

Comment: If you wanna have dynamic contents then you need other tools such as markdown or whatever works best. If you wanna keep very simple dont use Redux for this case and just use React Context api